# Magento 2 - Estimate Shipping and Tax cart does not calculate or include my custom shipping method's rate

Tags: cart, calculation, magento2.2, tax, shipping-method

I have used a custom shipping method and when you go to the Estimate Shipping and Tax cart, my custom shipping method 'rate' is not being added into the Order Total.

As you can see the image below.

[estimate-shipping-tax-cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtRCh.jpg)

When I select my shipping method, the rate is shown as 0.00

But for Flat Rate the rate is being calculated properly.

[estimate-shipping-tax-cart-with-flat-rate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CT8F.jpg)

I would like to know how to fix this and why it's happening like that.

Answer (score 0):

Please check all your files  once, 
Try to create your custom shipping method using this https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-shipping-method/
that might help you. 
I have created using this referance and it works fine.